# Launching my app from Facebook messenger make it stay in Facebook activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm recognizing special links to enable my users to launch my Android app when clicking on a link like "http://popp.us/ABCDE", for exemple from the Facebook messenger

For this, I implement in my Manifest file, inside my main activity tag :

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="popp.us" />
</intent-filter>
```

It correctly works, but when I click the home button and relaunch the Facebook app, Facebook is still showing my own app. **It seems to have launched my main activity inside Facebook app task.**

Does someone know a way to force Facebook (or other apps) to launch my app in another task ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour since Honeycomb and I strongly encourage you to keep it.

That said, you can escape the task by setting the `launchMode` `<activity>` attribute to `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. See the [documentation for more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). This will require you to use a separate Activity for that `intent-filter`, since it would mess up the normal use of the Activity in your app.

Comment: Actually when I open the link with Chrome instead of my app, then go back home and launch the Facebook app again, I'm on the the Facebook activity, not the Chrome one...

Comment: Fair enough, they could be using this exact method to launch a new task. It was definitely a major change that first became widely known with ICS. Sharing something with Gmail starts Gmail in the same task, for example. I'm not sure if it reparents it if the Gmail main task is launched, it probably should.